# Is there any way to use python libraries like pandas etc to Sikuli script? Or can I run Sikuli .py file through any python interpreter?

Tags: python, sikuli-x

Is there any way to use python libraries like pandas etc to Sikuli script? Or can I run Sikuli .py file through any python interpreter?

I have written a script that runs through SikuliX UI using run button as well as through the command line eg `C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Sikuli2\sikulixide-2.0.4.jar -r C:\Users\*****\Desktop\Sikuli2\Calculator.sikuli`.

I also tried `from sikuli import *` and `from sikuli.Sikuli import *` but I'm not able to run the script into any python interpreter say Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cant use sikuli in python (for now)
2. You can use some python libraries - just try them to see if the work with jython